# Difference in two types of command that uses grep

Tags: command-line, grep

So, here we have two commands:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep " \install\ "
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep install
```

Why are the outputs of these commands different? And can you please explain the first command a little. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can it be that the first one has a typo and was meant to look like that? `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "` (position of the first backslash!)

Comment: @ByteCommander - Both seems to show the same output.

Comment: The first slash of the first command does not make much sense. It escapes `i`, which does not have any special meaning anyway, so it is equivalent to `grep " install\ "`.

Comment: and `backslash-space` wouldn't have any special meaning either, so it's the difference between `grep " install "` (with spaces) and `grep install` (without)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first part of your two commands (`cat FILENAME`) is always the same and just prints the specified file's content to the STDOUT stream. I will not explain it any further.

The point of our interest is the `grep` part.

#### Syntax of `grep`:

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

You can pass `grep` some options to tweak its behaviour (e.g set the used RegEx flavour or control the output formatting), but those are not used in your case.

The next single argument must be the pattern to match, where a **regular expression** ("RegEx") or a fixed string (if `grep` is called with the `-F` option) is required. In your example, this is the `install` or `"\ install\ "` part. I will explain it in the next paragraph.

After that, you specify the source of the data to match. This can either be a file name, or nothing. In the second case, `grep` will read from the STDIN stream (standard input: normally what you type with the keyboard), where you pipe (`|`) the output from the previous command.

#### How to correctly pass the "PATTERN" argument?

The pattern parameter must be a single argument. That means, you can't just pass several words or anything containing spaces or shell special characters here, because spaces are treated as argument separators in Bash and probably every other shell as well, and shell special characters such as `;` will break the command.

But you have two options to include spaces into the pattern to match anyway:

- Put the entire string to match in single (`'...'`) or double (`"..."`) quotes. This way, the shell parses the entire quotes-enclosed string as one argument and passes it on to `grep`.
- Escape every space in the pattern with a backslash (`\`). That means, you write a backslash before every space which you don't want to be seen as argument separator by the shell. But note that if you want to have an actual backslash in the pattern, you must escape it as well, by writing another backslash before it.

If we now analyse the difference of your two `grep` command examples, we see the difference in what they match:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

This matches the pattern `install`. (Note the leading and trailing space!)

Here we see both methods: double quotes around the entire pattern and backslash-escaping the spaces inside it. It's superfluous to be honest, one would have been enough. Although it doesn't hurt in this case, you should not do this and decide on one method. Usually I would recommend to use quotation marks, as it's easier to read.

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep install
```

This matches the pattern `install`. (No surrounding spaces.)

Here the pattern only consists of the word `install`, nothing else. No spaces.

#### Difference between your commands:

As I said, the first of your examples only matches the word `install` when it is surrounded by spaces. It would not match if e.g. there's a full stop or any other character directly before or after it instead. It would also not match the word directly at the beginning or end of a line.

The second example does not care about any spaces before or after the word `install`. It also matches at line beginnings and endings as well as if it is surrounded by any punctuation. It even matches if there is a word containing this letter sequence anywhere, e.g. "uninstall", "reinstall" or "installation" too!

#### Example with correct/useful backslash escaping:

As in the example you provided the backslashes are superfluous, here the same example without quotes, but with backslash escaping only instead:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep \ install\
```

Or if you want to match the string "I like Ubuntu" in a file `/home/you/path with spaces/textfile` without using quotes, you would do that like this:

```
grep I\ like\ Ubuntu /home/you/path\ with\ spaces/textfile
```

You see that you must escape spaces in path- or filenames as well - or quote them. The line above is equal to the line below:

```
grep "I like Ubuntu" "/home/you/path with spaces/textfile"
```

Comment: There is just one more question. Can you please show another example that shows use of backlash?

Comment: Done. See my last paragraph, please.

Comment: Thanx Byte, you are awesome!

Answer (score 4):

The second (simpler) form will match the given string anywhere in a line: so for example it will match strings like **install**ation, re-**install**, **install**ed etc.

The first expression will only match **install** where it has a space at each end. The backslashes are something of a red herring since the quotes are already enough (and the first one - needlessly - escapes the `i` rather than the space): however it could have been written using *just* backslash escapes as

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep \ install\
```

(NB there is a literal space character at the end of the above command).

---

Adding a single space to the pattern is a bit of a hack IMHO: it won't work if the pattern is separated by other whitespace (tabs or line endings). A better option might be to use explicit word boundaries e.g.

```
grep '\binstall\b' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

or use the `-w` (`--word-regexp`) switch

```
grep -w 'install' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

(although these include hyphens as well as whitespace - so the equivalence isn't exact). If you **really** want whitespace separated instances of the pattern, then you can use the `[[:space:]]` POSIX character class e.g.

```
grep '[[:space:]]install[[:space:]]' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Answer (score 3):

**The first command:**

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep " \install\ "
```

As @ByteCommander pointed out, there may be a typo and the command should be

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

This would match the string `install` with a trailing and a leading whitespace. This could also be achieved by using `grep -w "install"`. Also, the `\` is not needed, when you use quotes.

**The second command:**

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep install
```

This command also matches strings, that contain `install`. For example "**install**ed".

---

**Test Case:**
content of testfile:

```
foo
bar
foobar
foo bar
```

Run:

```
cat file1.txt | grep foo
foo
foobar
foo bar

cat file1.txt | grep -w foo
foo
foo bar

cat file1.txt | grep "foo "
foo bar
```